# iOS SDK: RMInteractiveSourceOutputTypeTeaser - is there anyway to get back a key/value like in mapbox.js?

Tags: mapbox

I've worked a lot with mapbox.js and just now dipping my feet into iOS. Everything is groovy but when working with a UTFGrid layer it seems like you can only get back flat html such as this when using ***RMInteractiveSourceOutputTypeTeaser***

```
<strong>FID: </strong>182130<br>
<strong>Parcel: </strong>01000170-86<br> 
<strong>Address: </strong>32 MONROE<br>
<strong>City: </strong>detroit<br>
```

is there anyway to get back something like a javascript object like what is returned from mapbox.js?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily get a JavaScript object back from the UTFGrid endpoint, for example see here:

https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/justin.map-t5ae6kmf/8/152/103.grid.json

You get back whatever you've coded into the map, so you could encode a JSON string or whatever you want when making the map. See here for more info:

https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/crashcourse/tooltips/